# British 60s or 70s TV series about dangerous advances in science

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a TV series that I watched in Britain in the late 60s or early 70s. I think it ran for a few seasons.

I believe it was set in Britain in the near future. It involved a group of scientists who investigate dangerous advances in science (I think mainly by companies who didn't care how they made their money).

I considered it science fiction as the problematic scientific advances were ones that had not been made at the time but seemed plausible (I have no idea if any of them actually came about).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you thinking of [Doomwatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomwatch)?

It was produced in the UK between 1970 and '72; from Wikipedia:

> The formal name of the protagonist's organization was "Department for
> the Observation and Measurement of Scientific Work". Officially
> Doomwatch was an agency dedicated to preserving the world from dangers
> of unprincipled scientific research. In the words of one character,"We
> were set up to investigate any scientific research, Public or Private,
> which could possibly be harmful to Man." Its actual intended purpose
> was to form a body with little power meant in order to stifle public
> protest and secure green votes. However, the incorruptible Spencer
> Quist and his allies soon gave the agency some actual power and influence.

Comment: That's the one! Thank you.